# Kile - no dialog when file is changed on disk

Tags: kile, changes

I recently updated Kile to version 2.9.91.

After updating, when a source file is changed on disk by something other than Kile (e.g. because I am using Dropbox, and some collaborator edited the file), Kile does not notify it anymore.
Also, it does not reload the source file automatically.
Therefore, if I save the file with Kile without noticing a change on disk, I destroy all changes made by others.

Is there a way to make Kile notify a change on disk, as it used to do in older versions?

Comment: This sems to be a wider KDE issue, I have the same problem in Kate Version 18.04.0.

Comment: You can use reload oprion(File->Reload) short key F5. When you know someone changed the file.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox has its own way to tackle this, see here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/badge-collaborate.

However, using kile or another editor to prevent you from zapping somebody else' work of hours, seems really risky. At least everybody should load down the files, edit them locally and check before uploading.

A better solution would be to use a version control system, maybe online like github.com .

Comment: This issue is annoying also using Git. For instance, if a `git pull` changes the file I'm working on, I would like to be notified. Instead Kile keeps showing the old version.

Comment: I also face the same problem. Kile should do reload. Gedit provide reload when the file is changed in the disk.

Comment: @alhelal And if the file is changed exactly at the point where you rewrote something? That would be lost!